# Android MediaPlayer - I/O error - File not found

Tags: android, io, android-mediaplayer

I have a res/raw folder made in the project in which I placed a single file t.mp4. I intended to use a textureview to play the video file using the SurfaceTextureAvailable listener by implementing the relevant interface.

I created a mediaplayer object in the onSurfaceTextureAvailable method

```
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        Surface s = new Surface(surface);
        Log.d("debug", "Surface Texture Available");
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.t));
            Log.d("debug", "data source set");
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
            Log.d("debug", "Surface set");
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            Log.d("debug", "prepared");
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            Log.d("debug", "listeners set");
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This worked fine the first few times I ran the app, but after working on another (non-related) part of my project, it suddenly stopped working.

In the log, I keep getting an IOException, which I am 90% sure is because the application cannot find the file.

What happened?

Cheers

Comment: What does logcat say about the exception?

Comment: 01-09 11:23:16.240  20537-20554/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)


01-09 11:23:16.243  20537-20537/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Comment: I tried changing the setDataSource by using a FileInputStream object. 

Then I got a FileNotFound error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MediaPlayer.create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) in place of `new MediaPlayer()`/`setDataSource()` to easily create a MediaPlayer for a raw resource:

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.t);
```

Comment: I tried removing mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); Then in the try catch block, replaced setDataSource with mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.t); Tried running and the app crashed with java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare()' on a null object reference

Comment: I also tried simply mMediaPlayer = mediaPLayer.create(this, R.raw.t); mMediaPLayer.start(); and I got an IOException - create failed:
    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
            at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1125)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:931)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:902)